# Oracle SQL update double-check locking

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Suppose we have table **A** with fields **time: date**, **status: int**, **playerId: int**, **serverid: int**

We added constraint on time, playerid and serverid (**UNQ_TIME_PLAYERID_SERVERID**)

At some time we try to update all rows in table A with new status and date: 
  ***update status = 1, time = sysdate where serverid=XXX and status != 1 and time > sysdate***

Problem that there are two separated processes on separate machines that can execute same update at same sysdate.

And **UNQ_TIME_PLAYERID_SERVERID** violation occurs!

Is there any possibility to force Oracle check where cause before concrete update (when lock on row acquired)?

I do not want to use any **'select for update'** things

Comment: Why is this a problem?  Just catch the error and ignore it.

Comment: I dont want to simply ignore error. Yes, it is possible. But I want to know actually if there any possibility to write update that error will not appear at all.

Comment: You cann't. Just after you've got positive answer the table (row) can be locked. The only reliable way of doing things like that is try catch.

Comment: What if there are 2 records with the same playerId and a different time that satisfy the where clause? Than even one update query will hit your constraint. You might want to reconsider your application logic.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk yes, situation when for same player id we have 2 or more times which are possible. Yes you correct. We have another field in index. I will update question

Comment: Thanks for the update, but... what if there are 2 records with the same playerId and serverId and a different time? One update query will still hit your constraint. Your problem is not restricted to "multiple processes"; I think you need to reconsider your batch processing.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really the same update 100% of the time, then just catch the exception and ignore it.

In case you want to prevent an error occuring in the first place, you need to implement some logic to prevent the second update statement from ever executing.

I could think of a "lock table" just for this purpose. Create a table TABLE_A_LOCK_TB (add columns based on what information you want to have stored there for administrative reasons, e.g. user who set the lock or a timestamp, ...).

Before you execute an update statement on table A, just insert a row to TABLE_A_LOCK_TB. Once an update was successful, delete said row.

Before executing any update statement on table A just check whether the TABLE_A_LOCK_TB has a dataset. If it doesn't your update is good to go, if it does you don't execute the update.

To make this process easier you could just write a package for "locking" and "unlocking" table A by inserting / deleting a row from the TABLE_A_LOCK_TB. Also implement a function to check the "lock status".

If you need this logic for several tables you can also make it dynamic by just having a column holding the table name in TABLE_A_LOCK_TB and checking against that.

In your application logic you can handle every update like this then (pseudocode):

```
IF your_lock_package.lock_status(table_name) = false THEN 

     your_lock_package.set_lock(table_name);
     -- update statement(s)
     your_lock_package.release_lock(table_name);

ELSE
    -- "error" handling / information to user + exit
```